# Confusing 'r' sounds

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, sounds, silent-letters, spelling-pronunciations

In their kids song ["Crazy ABCs"](http://www.metrolyrics.com/crazy-abcs-lyrics-barenaked-ladies.html), the Barenaked Ladies sing about words that start with confusing sounds:

> A is for aisle
>
> B is for bdellium
>
> C is for czar

However, when the song gets to "r":

> R is for R-gyle
>
> No, it isn't
>
> OK, you're right; I couldn't find a good "r" word

So my question is: Is there an "r" word that would fit into this song?  If not, is there anything special about "r" that explains why not?

Comment: R never changes, because it's necessary for "Talk like a Pirate Day".

Comment: Pronounciation of "R" varies greatly.  See it's use in Japanese, Italian, or Scottish English. Isn't "Argyle" a great example? It's simply sn opposite case to those they're mocking above.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center. It's about trivia and, though of interest, should be asked elsewhere.

Comment: Q and Z don't seem to be covered properly either.

Comment: @Edwin, what's wrong with qat?

Comment: I suppose they could use a word spoken by Barry Kripke or Elmer Fudd.

Comment: @Dancrumb There aren't all that many words beginning q-a-consonant in the lexicon, but I think the q is pronounced k in them all. Qu is a digraph, and th, sh etc aren't given special treatment in the song.

Comment: @Edwin: q is for "qi" (beloved by Scrabble-players)

Comment: @sumelic Z doesn't seem to be covered properly. And as you well know, 'Help me compile a list of very unusual pronunciations' does not fit in with the site's ethos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rzedowski's pine](http://www.iucnredlist.org/details/33924/0), if you base your pronunciation on the Polish one, would be "zhe-DAWF-skee's pine". However, I would imagine a lot of people don't pronounce it based on the Polish pronunciation, since few English speakers are familar with Polish. So who knows, some people probably use /r/ here ("redouski").

Comment: An American who had been conditioned to oronounce some Polish names nearly correctly. ( a la "ski-shef-ski") for coach Mike Krzyzewski), might say ze-DOW-sky, and that would fit the song.